# Nginx - Redirect domain to localhost:port content

Tags: nginx, server

I installed Nginx on my server (my server uses WHM). And on this server has two accounts. Each account will run a server a NextJS site and each account has its own domain.

**Site1** will run on port 3000

**Site2** will run on port 3004

What I want to do is:

I want to access **domain1** I see the content of my **site1** in NextJS that runs on **localhost:3000**

And when I access **domain2** I see the content of my **site2** on NextJS running on **localhost:3004**

I tried to do a Nginx implementation for **site1**. But when I accessed it I saw a Cpanel screen, and the url was **dominio1/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi**

Here's the Nginx implementation I tried to do:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name computadorsolidario.tec.br www.computadorsolidario.tec.br ;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3004;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

So how do I do this setting for nginx to have this behavior? And I'm changing the correct file?

*Note: I created the configuration file in **/etc/nginx/conf.d/users/domain1/domio1.conf** And within **/etc/nginx/conf.d/users** have several configuration files with the name of the accounts you have on the server. (They are already implemented.)*

Comment: Have you tried `location /domain1 { proxy_pass http://localhost:3000 ...` and `location /domain2 { proxy_pass http://localhost:3004 ...`?

Comment: Not yet! I will try!

Comment: Not work... Here is my conf file with /domain1

Comment: server {
    server_name computadorsolidario.tec.br www.computadorsolidario.tec.br;
    listen 80;

    root /home/computadorsolida/public_html;

    location /computadorsolidario.tec.br {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3004;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}

Comment: It leads to the domain/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage url.cgi not to the app in next

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
upstream app1_server {
    server app1:8501;
}

upstream app2_server {
    server app2:8501;
}


server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   server_name trace.devops.rightsense.ai;
   

   location / {
        proxy_pass http://app1_server;

        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
   }
}

server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   server_name demo.devops.rightsense.ai;
   

   location / {
        proxy_pass http://app2_server;

        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
   }
}
```

Each domain listens on same port and reverse-proxies to local network on the ports you specify. To differentiate between hosts, specify the server_name field.

Comment: I tried this, and get Forbidden on my custom domain

Comment: Using the above configuration for 2 different sites on port 80. But it is opening same site for both for both domains.

Comment: @humkins answer is correct: "proxy_pass" directive is not allowed here...